# Run React Js as a response of ajax call

Tags: reactjs, ajax

I want to run an AJAX call on a click event .

```
<div class="response-container"></div>
function onItemClick(element) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/page/react",
    type: "post",
    data: {
      id: '123'
    },
    success: function (response) {
    $(".response-container").html(response)
    }
  });
}
```

The response data from AJAX call contains reactJS code :

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/json?id...", {
      method: "POST",
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({data:data}) )
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));

  }
  render() {
    return this.state.data.map((item, i) => (
      <p>{item.name}</p>
    ));
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

The main problem is that the result of AJAX call is not be shown and reactJS code does not work in this case, but when I run React page directly , it will be run, but I want to run it by onclick function and ajax call .
I receive this warning:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience
```